# Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder could not be converted to string in filtering

Tags: laravel-5

I'm making search functionality, and like to add filter my search and my code is like

CODE AREA =========================================================

```
public function search(Request $request) {

    $q = $request->input('q');

    $resources = Resource::where('title','LIKE','%'.$q.'%')

                    ->orWhere('name','LIKE','%'.$q.'%')

                    ->orWhere('batch','LIKE','%'.$q.'%')

                    ->orWhere('mba/emba','LIKE','%'.$q.'%')

                    ->orWhere('topic','LIKE','%'.$q.'%')

                    ->orWhere('year','LIKE','%'.$q.'%')

                    ->orWhere('company','LIKE','%'.$q.'%')

                    ->orWhere('supervisor','LIKE','%'.$q.'%')

                    ->orWhere('abstract','LIKE','%'.$q.'%') 

                    ->latest()->paginate(5);
    if(count($resources) > 0) {

        return view('blog', [

            'resources' => $resources

        ]);

    }else {

         echo "there is nothing like that result";

    }
```

## }

I'm search with an input value and I would like to filter
and i change my code like that.... so I can filter from existing Query

CODE AREA============================================================

```
 public function search(Request $request) {

    $q = $request->q;

    $resources = Resource::where('title','LIKE','%'.$q.'%')

                    ->orWhere('name','LIKE','%'.$q.'%')

                    ->orWhere('batch','LIKE','%'.$q.'%')

                    ->orWhere('mba/emba','LIKE','%'.$q.'%')

                    ->orWhere('topic','LIKE','%'.$q.'%')

                    ->orWhere('year','LIKE','%'.$q.'%')

                    ->orWhere('company','LIKE','%'.$q.'%')

                    ->orWhere('supervisor','LIKE','%'.$q.'%')

                    ->orWhere('abstract','LIKE','%'.$q.'%');

    $author = $request->author;

    if($author != '') {


        //"This is where the error message show"
        //"I would like to filter from above query"
        =======================================================
        $resources = $this->$resources->where('name', $author) 
        =======================================================
        dd($resources);
    }

    $resources = $resources->latest()->paginate(5);               
    if(count($resources) > 0) {
        return view('blog', [
            'resources' => $resources
        ]);
    }else {
         echo "there is nothing like that result";
    }
}
```

And so, I'm end up with getting message => "Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder could not be converted to string"

and i'm noob...so plz help....and thank you all

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `$this->$resources`.

PHP assumes that `$resources` is a property of the current class (`$this`) and therefore tries to convert it to a string.

Replace the line with `$resources = $resources->where('name', $author);` to fix it.

Comment: yep! i idid that ...and my final problem is
i want to filter from the search result and i have no idea to query on the current collection

Comment: I have two input one is "q" and other is "author"  I search with "q" and next time i search with "author".......the problem is i can't get  value from "q" again.......and nothing comes back'

Comment: Not exactly sure what you mean but you can pass `$q` to the `blob` view and repopulate the search field so the user doesn't have to enter it again (and the same for the author).